# Everything Search by Default Results not valid

Tags: search

We have our SharePoint online site collection set up for search using the Out of the Box settings. The search center is not working when using the initial everything search. The results are the exact same no matter what search criteria you enter. It is a list of files based on the most recent file that was modified.

However, when you click on the refiners on the left, the results then become correct. Strange behavior I have never seen, strange things are a foot at the Circle K.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check if anyone messed with the search result webpart.

To do this edit the page and then check the properties of the search result webpart. if the query string is set to something specific it might mess with the results

Comment: I went through the search section of the site with a consultant and he has a "I have no idea what is going on" look on his face. The search results webpart is set to the defaults with the result sources have everything set to active.

Comment: the query string section of the result webpart would be the interesting thing... Not the box on the page, but the query string in the result webpart under properties

Answer (score 0):

It seems your search box is not linked with search results.
Make sure your search results query box contains below query text:

{searchboxquery}

Comment: I poked around the query box for the both the search page and the one on the results page and it looks like it is all out of the box config as every is set to defaults. All of the query rules are straight out of the box config as well. The selected query is set to Documents (system) and Local SharePoint Results is set to default but all others are active as well.